# How can I show the model date in the plot in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I can use the time plot, but it shows the time in days not in dates. That is why I want to use plot, where I can give my model date using the function

```
date()
```

in the x-axis, but it is not working because we can only have double values in the plot.

Kindly let me know how I can achieve the date in the X-axis of the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format the dates in the appearance section of the graphs, in the time axis format field

Comment: how I can format the dates? I am trying but t is not working for me.

Comment: check the properties section of the graph... there are many sections... look for the appearace section... it should be super easy to find... if you don't, show a screenshot of the properties section of your graphs...